# Scss/sass compilation it converts string variable(content) to a different string

Tags: sass

I have in configuration file a variable:

```
$temp_icon = "\75";
```

later in code:

```
.signature {
    content: "$temp_icon"
}
```

When I compile using gulp-sass/node-sass I get:

```
  .signature {
        content: "u"
    }
```

which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395).

You can install [gulp-sass-unicode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-unicode) plugin and it will automatically fix the issue for you.

What does it do?
For example, we have style.scss:

```
$testContent: "\f26e";

#test{
  content:  $testContent;
}
```

And gulp task:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('SimpleSASS', function(){
  gulp.src(['style.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest( "css/" ));
});
```

After run gulp task SimpleSASS, in file css/style.css will be next:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
#test {
  content: "";
}
```

But, if we add gulp-sass-unicode (see "Usage"), file css/style.css will have this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
#test {
  content: "\f26e";
}
```